# Firebase Storage CORS error while uploading file from Vue webapp

Tags: firebase, vue.js, cors

I am trying to upload a pdf file from vue webapp with this code

```
let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
let uploadTask = storageRef.child("results").put(file);
```

When I select the file, in the console, I am seeing this error.

```
(Reason: header ‘x-firebase-gmpid’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response)
```

I have tried setting cors config via gsutil

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
    "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

still getting the same error.

Comment: Update the gsutil config to have `"responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "x-firebase-gmpid"]`

Comment: Still same error. Adding won't solve the problem since the header ‘x-firebase-gmpid’ is not allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the most recent firebase js version, v7.9.2. If you downgrade firebase to v7.9.1 the error will go away.